# Using AngularJS with $window.sessionStorage (using Onsen UI)

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I am trying to implement a simple login feature. I want to have the DOM load a different element based on whether the $window.sessionStorage.currentUserId5 session exists or not. But the conditional statement I have added to .run() just keeps using the else{} statement

```
<script>
   var app =  ons.bootstrap('app',  ['onsen','angular-svg-round-progress','nvd3','ngStorage']).run(function($rootScope,$window){ 

        if($window.sessionStorage.currentUserId5)
        {
           $("#menudiv").html('<ons-sliding-menu var="menu" id="menusliding" main-page="main.html" menu-page="menux.html" max-slide-distance="85%" type="reveal" side="left"  ></ons-sliding-menu>');
        }
        else{

           $("#menudiv").html('<ons-sliding-menu var="menu" id="menusliding" main-page="login.html" menu-page="menux.html" max-slide-distance="85%" type="reveal" side="left"  ></ons-sliding-menu>');               
        }           

       });
</script>  


<div id="menudiv"></div>
```

**Controller**

User clicks button and this is called, $window.sessionStorage should be created here

```
    $http.post('http://xxx-xxx.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/apipost/checkuserlogin', parameter, config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            // if login, user session created, redirected to index.html
            if(data['result'] == 'success'){

                $window.sessionStorage.currentUserId5 = '5'
                $window.location.reload();

            }
            else {
                // else error pop up 
                ons.notification.alert({
                  message: 'Please try again'
                });   
            }
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be rude, but I think the question is not really related to Onsen UI. Even though you're using it, I doubt that the usage of Onsen UI changes your actual question. (Unless Onsen UI breaks the code in some way.)

What you seem to be using is the `ngStorage` module. From what I've seen it seems like the normal way to access local and sessionStorage is just by having them directly, rather than through $window.

So you can try to just require `$sessionStorage` and use it directly. If you think that the issue may be connected to some browser reloading somehow breaking the session etc you could try `$localStorage` and see if it works. The final thing you could try is just see if the normal `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` work for you.

And if you want to debug what happens then you can do something like

```
$http.post('...', parameter, config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert(data.result);

    if(data['result'] == 'success'){
        $window.sessionStorage.currentUserId5 = '5'
        alert($window.sessionStorage.currentUserId5);
        $window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Usually it's better to use `console.log` instead of `alert`, but in this case `alert` can be better since it will stop the execution until you click ok.

The other option is to click the `preserve log` option in the browser inspector's console. To open the chrome console you can do `Ctrl + Shift + J` or `Cmd + Opt + J`. The other browsers also have similar consoles where you can see the logs from `console.log`. Usually these types of issues can be debugged without the need of external help.